# How to create "one to many to one" relationship using code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following tables in my database:

Cases

- Id (PK)

CaseTogs

- TogId (PK, FK)
- CaseId (FK)

Togs

- TogId (PK)
- Name

There is a one to one relationship between Tog and CaseTog (There is another table with a one to one relationship to Togs but that is not important for the question). There is a one to many relationship between Cases and CaseTogs.

I would like the Case entity object to have a collection of Togs, so that I can do this:

```
_entities.Cases.Where(c => c.Togs.Any(t => t.Name == "Foo"));
```

When I create the model using the designer it works. When I create the model using code first, it doesn't. I get the following error:

----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid column name 'Case_Id'.

Here is the sql that is being generated:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id] 
FROM [cases].[Cases] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Togs] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Case_Id]) AND (N'Foo' = [Extent2].[Name])
)
```

Here is the code that I am using to setup the relationships in Code First and my entities:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CaseTog>()
            .HasKey(ct => ct.TogId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CaseTog>()
            .HasRequired(ct => ct.Case)
            .WithMany(c => c.CaseTogs)
            .HasForeignKey(ct => ct.CaseId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CaseTog>()
            .HasRequired(ct => ct.Tog)
            .WithRequiredDependent(t => t.CaseTog);


[Table("dbo.Cases")]
public partial class Case
{
    public Case()
    {
        Togs = new HashSet<Tog>();
        CaseTogs = new HashSet<CaseTog>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<CaseTog> CaseTogs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tog> Togs { get; set; }
}

[Table("dbo.CaseTogs")]
public partial class CaseTog
{
    public int TogId { get; set; }
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public Case Case { get; set; }
    public Tog Tog { get; set; }
}

[Table("Togs")]
public partial class Tog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual CaseTog CaseTog { get; set; }
    public virtual Case Case { get; set; }
}
```

I could write the code like this:

```
_entities.Cases.Where(c => c.CaseTogs.Any(ct => ct.Tog.Name == "Foo"))
```

but the first code is simpler. And since it works with the designer, I know that it is possible.

Comment: lots of working examples on the internet as well as here on `SO` https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23+create+%E2%80%9Cone+to+many+to+one%E2%80%9D+relationship+using+code+first

Comment: Do you mean that it works with database-first? If so, this is because you don't have this `CaseTog` entity and there is a many to many association between `Case` and `Tog`.

Comment: It works with database first. There is a one to many relationship between Case and Tog

Comment: And `Tog` doesn't have a `CaseId`? And where is `CaseTog` in the db-first model?